# How to isolate reusable small functions in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a function that let's say generates a random string for generating a token. I have this function in my `methods:{}` and I use it in my div without any problem.

But I am trying to put this function in it's own separate file so I can import it for future use, so I put a `functions.js` file inside my `src` like this:

```
// /src/functions.js
export default {
    // generate tokes
  tokenGenerator () { ... }

}
```

And in my `src/components/foo.vue` I am importing this file (no issues  with importing)

```
<template>
 <div> {{ tokenGenerator }} </div>
</template>

<script>
import tokenGenerator from '../../functions'
export default {
   data() {
      return ;
   }
}
</script>
```

This should work, but it doesn't. Importing is not the issue, but something else.. the console error shows me that It can not find function tokenGenerator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one, you seem to be trying to import a single function, but `tokenGenerator` in your code is a reference to the whole object exported in your `functions` file.

Secondly, you cannot access plain javascript functions using Vue interpolation `{{ ... }}`. The template can only reference functions defined as methods on the related Vue instance.

You can use a mixin to do what you want:

```
// /src/functions.js
export default {
  methods: {
    // generate tokens
    tokenGenerator () { ... }
  }
}
```

<!>

```
<template>
  <div>{{ tokenGenerator }} </div>
</template>

<script>
import mixinFuncs from '../../functions'
export default { 
   mixins: [ mixinFuncs ],
}
</script>
```

[Here's the documentation on mixins.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

---

If you simply need access to the `tokenGenerator` function in your Vue script, then you can export it directly and import it:

```
// /src/functions.js
// generate tokens
export const tokenGenerator = () => { 
  //... 
}
```

<!>

```
<template>
  <div> {{ token }} </div>
</template>

<script>
import { tokenGenerator } from '../../functions'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      token: tokenGenerator()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[Here's a working example.](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kut66uGy9p-HjDukl79)

Comment: I don't think mixins are the only way. If you see at this vuejs code https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/master/src/api/index.js  you can see in this file (first line and last) https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/master/src/components/Login.vue#L31-L53 that it is imported simply the way I have shown. I don't want to use mixins  when a simpler and better options is available. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: That example uses a function from an imported object in a Vue instance's method. If that's what you're trying to do then yes you can definitely just import the function and use it in your script (see my edit). But, if you are trying to use that function in a template, it needs to be set as a method or property of the Vue instance, and the easiest way to do that is via mixins (although you could also do something like in Kumar_14's answer).

Comment: @hidar Mixins are a powerful pattern for VueJS and are worth the time to learn how to use them well

Comment: Sorry to revoke the accepted mark, but I just tried your answer today and it does not work. I am talking about the second example.  I get `vue.esm.js:434 [Vue warn]: Property or method "token" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.` error.. maybe something has changed in vue

Comment: It should definitely work. Are you absolutely sure your `data()` method is returning an object with a `token` property and that you aren't using `token` in the template of another component?

Answer (score 1):

Export it in this way in functions.js:

```
export class util {
    static tokenGenerator() {
       //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

In foo.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ tokenGenerator }} </div>
</template>

<script>
import { util } from '../../functions';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
       textData: util.tokenGenerator
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: You could do something like this but you'd probably want to set a method instead of a data property and you still can't reference `tokenGenerator` in the template

Comment: This is close enough but as I have mentioned in the comment on the second answer, I think there is a better alternative to this one